# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command, how to solve the error and what is the cause of the error

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

While I am executing the android automation test cases using Appium most of the time in the middle I am getting the error:

> "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original
>   error: Error: socket hang up (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information)"

I am not able to understand what can be the cause of this error. Some times I observe some test cases running in one execution again if I am executing the same getting this error and test cases getting failed. Please help me in this.

I am using Appium 1.6.5

Comment: now a days I am not getting a single answer from stack overflow. no one is responding to give any answer. I am not getting any help.

Comment: Can you please add your code snippet?

Comment: I am doing it using page object module frame work.

Comment: forgotpw.forgotPasswordNativeInvalidEmail("Tank78666g@gmail.com");
  forgotpw.clickForgotpassword();
  forgotpw.resetpasswordFailPopup();
  forgotpw.alertMsgForScocialMailID();
  forgotpw.clickOkPopup();
  forgotpw.clearMailID();
  forgotpw.forgotPasswordNativeInvalidEmail("wholefood123@gmail.com"); Like this I have written some times all re passed some times from middle its showing the exception and its happening for all test cases. Can you please tell me in which case this exception occurs for android automation